# Alternative to not open a new tab | javascript | window.open

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing this today but don't want it to open a new tab. I want it to use the same page:

```
<td>
            <form>
            <select name="URL" onchange="window.open(this.value);">
                <option selected="selected" value="">...</option>
                <option value="ListArchivedProjects">List archived projects</option>
                <option value="ListArchivedCertificates">List archived certificates</option>
                <option value="SelectProject">List Projects</option>
                <option value="ListCertificates">List Certificates</option>
                <option value="AddProjectForm.jsp">+ Add new project</option>
                <option value="AddCertificateForm.jsp">+ Add new certificate</option>
            </select>
            </form>
        </td>
```

Comment: Just replace the window.open(...) by window.loction=this.value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the same page?

```
location.href = this.value;
```

Comment: Also to use a method of the location object, [`location.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location.assign) is an option.

Answer (score 1):

```
        <td>
        <form>
        <select name="menu1" id="menu1">
            <option selected="selected" value="">...</option>
            <option value="ListArchivedProjects">List archived projects</option>
            <option value="ListArchivedCertificates">List archived certificates</option>
            <option value="SelectProject">List Projects</option>
            <option value="ListCertificates">List Certificates</option>
            <option value="AddProjectForm.jsp">+ Add new project</option>
            <option value="AddCertificateForm.jsp">+ Add new certificate</option>
        </select>
          <script type="text/javascript">
              var urlmenu.onchange = function() {
              window.open( this.options[ this.selectedIndex ].value, '_self');
               };
        </script>
        </form>
    </td>
```